# Buscar/verificar si una palabra (string) es infinitiva

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Buenas. Mi problema es el siguiente: quiero implementar un programa en c++ que al introducir una palabra, es decir un string, me diga si es infinitivo o no. El programa se tiene que repetir cuantas veces desee el usuario (es decir, con un while). Con que la palabra sea infinitivo me refiero a que dicho string termine en "ar", "er", "ir" (reir, cantar, etc).

He intentado ver si algunas de estas funciones de esta pagina me podrian servir: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/. Pero en realidad no le veo la utilidad a ninguna para que me pueda solucionar mi problema o no sé como implementarlas.

Tengo dudas en como hacer la función que busca o verifica en una palabra sus terminaciones, es decir, si me verifica si es infinitivo o no (si termina en "-ar","-er","-ir"). Agradecería mucho su ayuda y sus respuestas

Comment: Me imagino que las palabras de entrada siempre serán verbos y tienes alguna parte de tu código para verificar esto, de lo contrario te reconocería como infinitivos palabras como "bipolar", "muladar", "fular", "vulgar", "alfiler", "alquiler", "alzheimer", "anteayer", "ayer", "cachemir", "tapir", entre muchísimas otras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La funcion que debes usar es [compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) con ella tendrias que hacer algo como esto

```
string str1 = "ar";
string str2 = "er";
string str3 = "ir";
string str4;
cin >> str4;
 if (str4.compare(str4.size()-2,2,str1) == 0)
     cout << "termina en ar" <<endl;
 if (str4.compare(str4.size()-2,2,str2) == 0)
     cout << "termina en er" <<endl;
 if (str4.compare(str4.size()-2,2,str3) == 0)
     cout << "termina en ir" <<endl;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido de mucho, aunque hay un pequeño error al principio, corregido sería: string str1 = "ar";
string str2 = "er"; string str3 = "ir"; string str4;

Comment: Total gracias por la observación

Comment: En futuras ocasiones, plantéate esperar a que se exponga el código con el que ha intentado resolver el problema. Se supone que este portal es para ayudar... y tomar como norma el ofrecerle a alguien que está aprendiendo la solución sin que se lo tenga que trabajar siquiera no supone ayuda alguna ya que la persona en cuestión no aprenderá absolutamente nada.

Comment: Este código falla cuando se proporcionan cadenas vacías y da falsos negativos cuando se introducen textos en MAYÚSCULAS.

Comment: Muchas gracias @eferion por el comentario, lo tendré en cuenta para futuras ocasiones, sin embargo en esta ocasión me pareció que la pregunta estaba bastante bien planteada, pues solo quería una dirección dentro de la libreria STRING en la cual buscar, preguntó cual función seria útil para su problema y yo le di la función que buscaba, (no como una pregunta super amplia) me parece que aprendió, pues editó mi respuesta, lo cual me indica que aprendió _algo._  De igual manera muchas gracias por tu observación-

Answer (score 1):

Este problema puede ser un candidato a ser resuelto con [expresiones regulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular).

---

Una de las posibles expresiones regulares para este propósito sería `[A-Za-z]+(?:ar|er|ir)`, que aplicada usando la librería [`<regex>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (incorporada a C++ en el estándar de 2011) quedaría así:

```
std::regex infinitivo("[A-Za-z]+(?:ar|er|ir)");
std::smatch match;

for (const auto &palabra : palabras)
{
    if (std::regex_match(palabra, match, infinitivo))
    {
        std::cout << '"' << palabra << "\" parece un unfinitivo.\n";
    }
}
```

Puede verse el código funcionando <kbd>[aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RJJebWhoXQihzZue)</kbd>.

---

El problema de esta aproximación es que como detector de verbos es muy malo, cualquier texto alfabético acabado en *ar*, *er* o *ir* es candidato a ser verbo aunque no lo sea... así pues:

- [*Kurir*](http://www.kurir.rs/) sería un candidato a verbo infinitivo aunque no sea una palabra en Español.
- *Mar* sería un candidato a verbo infinitivo aún sin ser un verbo.
- [*TER*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%ADo_Ter) no sería un candidato a verbo infinitivo... pero por estar en mayúsculas no por ser un nombre.

Adicionalmente, ¡*ir* es un verbo infinitivo y sería un falso negativo!, este último problema puede solucionarse modificando la expresión a: `(?:[A-Za-z]+(?:ar|er)|[A-Za-z]?ir)` pero respecto a detectar si una palabra es verbo o no requeriría mucho más trabajo.

Para acabar, es posible verificar la expresión regular sobre un texto de manera que ignore la diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas si se declara el objeto `std::regex` de la siguiente manera:

```
std::regex infinitivo("(?:[A-Za-z]+(?:ar|er)|[A-Za-z]?ir)", std::regex_constants::icase);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la consideraré para este caso también